# tablayout change tab selected textsize

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tablayout

[image]

> Tablayout.tab cant change selected textsize in code

.

[image]

> textAppearance can't set selectTextsize too.so how complete it?

Comment: Did you set the style of your TabLayout in the xml? Please include the xml in your question.

Comment: of course i set the style for TabLayout in xml,but i want to change the tabs textsize if it selected,it only can set a immobilization textsize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the following a try. Note to implement the tab selected listener as well.

```
TextView title = (TextView)(((LinearLayout ((LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tabPosition)).getChildAt(1));
title.setTextSize(...);
```

Comment: TextView title = (TextView)(((LinearLayout) ((LinearLayout) mTabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(tab.getPosition())).getChildAt(1));
                title.setTextSize(50);

Comment: title.setTextSize(50),this method is strange，if i setTextSize(10),it works,tab has small textsize,but when i setTextSize above 10,it always use default textsize whatever tab is selected or not.

Comment: Apologies, I am unable to answer your question as I've no prior knowledge regarding that. Perhaps you wish you open a new question with my answer to clarify your questions further.

Comment: whatever,thanks for your answer.i need open a new question for it

Answer (score 1):

```
 class OnTabSelectedListener implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab selectedTab) {
            LinearLayout tabLayout1 = (LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(selectedTab.getPosition());
            TextView tabTextView = (TextView) tabLayout1.getChildAt(1);
           // tabTextView.setTypeface(tabTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
            tabTextView.setTextSize(20);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab unselectedTab) {
            LinearLayout tabLayout1 = (LinearLayout)((ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(unselectedTab.getPosition());
            TextView tabTextView = (TextView) tabLayout1.getChildAt(1);
            //tabTextView.setTypeface(tabTextView.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
            tabTextView.setTextSize(15);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    }
```

Do anything with textview Enjoy....

Answer (score 1):

display bold text

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(tabSelectedListener)

private val tabSelectedListener = object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
  override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    tab?.view?.children?.forEach {
      if (it is TextView) {
        it.post {
          it.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.bold_font_name), Typeface.NORMAL)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
    tab?.view?.children?.forEach {
      if (it is TextView) {
        it.post {
          it.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.font_name), Typeface.NORMAL)
        }
      }
    }
  }

  override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
}
```